# Can not display local saved image in blazor server app

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-server-side

I try to display an image in a blazor server side app but it does not load. This is my code:

```
<img src="@imageSource" alt="..."/>
@code {
    private string? imageSource =  @"..\samplePic\logo.png";

}
```

I also tried this:

```
<img src="..\samplePic\logo.png" alt="..."/>
```

still not loading. But than I tried it with an online picture:

```
<img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/hand-building-trends-concept-wooden-blocks-closeup-wood-149391549.jpg" alt="..."/>
```

this worked. So how can I get my local pictures running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default you cannot access files outside of wwwroot (which is what you are doing with `..\`) because they do not exist in the server.

Your first possibility is to move your image in wwwroot.

Another possibility would be to specify a static folder to give access to files outside of wwwroot.

See the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0) about static files.